# Optimize my (simple) SQL query (joins)

Tags: sql, join, firebird

I have a query that seems to take far too long to execute. It's been a while (years) since I've done anything much beyond very simple select/update and v.simple joins so I'm more than a little rusty here!

```
SELECT count(distinct r.TAGCODE)
FROM RAWREADS r
where r.TAGCODE NOT IN (
    select distinct r.TAGCODE 
    from RAWREADS r, checkpoints c, guards g, INCIDENTITEMS i
        where r.TAGCODE = c.TAGNO
        or    r.TAGCODE = g.IDTAG
        or    r.TAGCODE = i.IDTAG
    );
```

The inner select seems to work correctly, if slowly (several seconds) but as soon as I add the outer 'count where not in' I end up having to kill my DB connection - so no good for working into an application! ;)

I hope the query above is clear what I'm trying to achieve...  fetch all rawread tags where that tag does not match the respective columns in checkpoints/guards/incidentitems.

I'm using the Flamebird database server (no choice on that) and FlameRobin to run the query if that matters.

At some point I also need to add a query to the outer select to ensure I don't select any rawreads where the tagcode is null or "".

I have removed a "char_length(tagcode) > 0" criteria from the out select in the hope of speeding things along but I think my problem is more fundamental than that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many databases (and maybe Firebird as well) cannot easily optimize NOT IN conditions. So you might try to rerwrite this as a NOT EXTISTS.

Additionally looking at the inner select, I think the way you are joining there is producing too many rows. It's not a real join but not a cartesian product either. Anyway I could imagine that doing a UNION in there is also more efficient.

So try this:

```
SELECT count(distinct r.TAGCODE)
FROM RAWREADS r
where NOT EXISTS (
    select 1
    from checkpoints c
    where c.tagno = r.tagcode
    union all
    select 1 
    from guards g
    where g.idtag = r.tagcode
    union all 
    select 1 
    from INCIDENTITEMS i
    where i.idtag = r.tagcode);
```

If you have indexes on `checkpoints(tagno)`, `guards(idtag)` and `incidentitems(idtag)` that should run fairly quick.

Comment: +1 : Possible to optimise further by using `WHERE NOT EXISTS(c) AND NOT EXISTS(g) AND NOT EXISTS (i)`?

Comment: @Dems: I don't think it will make a big difference. In any case the three selects on the tables will be run because I don't think the WHERE clause will short-circuiting and not run the other queries if not necessary. But it might be worth a try

Comment: Thanks horse(!). I've tried this query on my database, it returns faster than I can measure, so fast enough for my needs (it'll never be a massive dataset).

I shall have to go and read about unions now!

Answer (score 2):

subquery inside `NOT IN` will be called for each rows in `RAWREADS` and hence this query is running slowly. If you are running as a procedure, dump the subquery result in a temp table and do inner join with that temp table and do negative condition over `TAGCODE`

Comment: Thanks for the explanation about each row thing

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT count(distinct r.TAGCODE)
FROM RAWREADS r
where NOT EXISTS (
    select *  
    from  checkpoints c, guards g, INCIDENTITEMS i
        where r.TAGCODE = c.TAGNO
        or    r.TAGCODE = g.IDTAG
        or    r.TAGCODE = i.IDTAG
    );
```

if sql server

```
SELECT count(distinct r.TAGCODE)
FROM RAWREADS r
where NOT EXISTS (
    select TOp 1 1   
    from  checkpoints c, guards g, INCIDENTITEMS i
        where r.TAGCODE = c.TAGNO
        or    r.TAGCODE = g.IDTAG
        or    r.TAGCODE = i.IDTAG
    );
```

Comment: `IF SQL Server`? The question states Firebird...  Also, SQL Server *does not* require the `TOP 1` in an `EXISTS` query.  Check the execution plans.

Comment: @Dems: yeah, that's an urban legend that does not go away. People sometimes also believe that `select 1` will be faster than `select *` in an (NOT) EXISTS query which isn't the case with any modern DBMS (and probably never was).

Comment: Thanks for the input Ruzbeh, certainly works faster than the original query but the union answer seems to be fastest so far.

Answer (score 0):

The code bellow is compatible for Firebird 2.5 and it's fast.
I cant't test it now, but it's the idea.
It uses CTR to simplify subquery code.

```
with SQ1 as (
  select distinct r.TAGCODE as TAGCODE
  from RAWREADS r, checkpoints c, guards g, INCIDENTITEMS i
      where r.TAGCODE = c.TAGNO
      or    r.TAGCODE = g.IDTAG
      or    r.TAGCODE = i.IDTAG
)

SELECT count(distinct r.TAGCODE)
FROM RAWREADS r
left join SQ1 on (r.TAGCODE = SQ1.TAGCODE)
where SQ1.TAGCODE is NULL
```

Comment: How do you know it's fast if you haven't tested?

Answer (score 0):

In quite any RDBMS the best way to obtain an optimized NOT IN clause is to write a LEFT OUTER JOIN with the failing condition in the WHERE clause, like this:

```
SELECT count(distinct r.TAGCODE)
FROM RAWREADS r
left outer join checkpoints c on r.TAGCODE = c.TAGNO
left outer join guards g on r.TAGCODE = g.IDTAG
left outer join INCIDENTITEMS i on r.TAGCODE=i.IDTAG
where 
  c.TAGNO is null AND
  g.IDTAG is null AND
  i.IDTAG is null
```

From a general point of view, a NOT IN clause like this:

```
select * from TABLEA 
where TABLEA.ID NOT IN (SELECT ID from TABLEB)
```

can sucessfully converted in

```
select TABLEA.*
from TABLEA 
left outer join TABLEB ON TABLEA.ID=TABLEB.ID
where TABLEB.ID is null
```

if TABLEB has an index on column ID the query is really fast  in retrieving all the records from TABLEA that have no a counterpart in TABLEB